# How to automatically select and move down lines that begins with certain text in notepad++

Tags: batch, notepad++

I have this text file, where I need to move down a single line .. repeatedly.

**This is the original file**

```
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
specific-word txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
```

**and this is the file I need to have**

```
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
specific-word txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-txt-
```

The specific-word`enter code here` is the same but the remaining of the line is different, and I need to have it moved down only one line.

I used the line operation after clicking the line and choosing the option to move the line down, or the keyboard shortcut ctrl shift down

However I was hoping to have another automation as the file is really big, contains over 20k lines to be moved down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.*?specific-word.*)(\R)(.+)`
- Replace with: `$3$2$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(       # start group 1
  ^       # beginning of line
  .*?     # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  specific-word   # the word to search
  .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
)       # end group 1
(\R)    # group 2, any kind of linebreak
(.+)    # group 3, 1 or more any character but newline
```

**Replacement:**

```
$3      # content of group 3, the second line
$2      # content of group 2, linebreak
$1      # content of group 1, the first line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Appreciate your help. I'm trying to upvote your answer, but still no reputation points for me to save it.